# How to control the permission-related User Interface in the asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am new in developing using asp.net.

I use java(struts2) to do the web application before,it is easy to control this use the jsp tag or struts2 tags:
For example(suppose the "do something" operation need use login):

```
<s:if test="#session.user!=null">
    <span>do something</span>
</s:if>
```

So if a user did not login,he will never see the menu of "do something".

Now I wonder how to make it in the asp.net?

Is this controled in the xx.aspx.cs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to handle "membership" in asp.net. Microsoft has the [Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) as a built in solution. It seems however you have gone with a failrly simple one of your own devising.

You could handle your problem two ways using what you've already got.

In the aspx page you could have:

```
<% if(Session["user"] != null) { %> 
    <span>Do Something</span>
<% } %>
```

Preferably move the logic to the code behind page (.aspx.cs)
In your aspx page have

```
<span id="thisSpan" runat="server">Do Something</span>
```

Then in yout code behind page in the onPage Load event

```
thisSpan.Visible = Session["user"] != null;
```